# Как отследить первую авторизацию пользователя на сайте?

Tags: php

Как отследить первую авторизацию пользователя на сайте?

Comment: если есть история посещений в том или ином виде, то ее отсутствие будет явным признаком первой авторизации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый банальный способ: в базе создайте поле first_auth и после регистрации ставьте его в 0. Во время первой авторизации проверяете

```
if (!$first_auth) {
    // что-то делаете и ставите флаг first_auth в 1
}
```

Условие выполнится только один раз при первой авторизации

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например у меня, в таблице с пользователями есть столбик lvl, и, например, если пользователь ещё не активирован, то lvl = 0, если активирован - 1. Можешь при авторизации считывать значение lvl и если равно 1, то первый вход и присваиваешь значение 2, если равно 2, то не первый вход